# Order of ggplot2 stacked bar plot stacks not same as source data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm attempting to make a stacked bar chart in R with ggplot2, however, I'm unable to reproduce previous examples that I've found online.

The sample data:

```
d <- data.frame(year = factor(sample(2010:2014, 400, replace=T)), 
                continent = factor(sample(c("EU", "US", "Asia"), 400, replace=T)), 
                gender = factor(sample(c("male", "female"), 400, replace=T)), 
                amount = sample(20:5000, 400, replace=T))
```

The ggplot code:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=year, y=amount, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Should according to the [blog post by Christoph Herzog](https://theduke.at/blog/science/beginners-guide-to-creating-grouped-and-stacked-bar-charts-in-r-with-ggplot2/) produce the following chart without manually ordering the source data:

[image: Desired Results]

However, the actual results I get without applying any ordering is:

[image: Actual Results]

Is there anyone who can explain to me why this is? Has there been a change to ggplot2 that I haven't been able to find? Have I overlooked something?

---

Update: 1

I've tried forcing the order by using, but no luck:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=year, y=amount, fill=gender, order=as.numeric(row.names(d)))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I'm using ggplot2_2.2.1 and R version 3.3.2.

---

Update: 2

The following code yields unsorted results, however there are several issues.

1. The plot is limited to the first 5000 (amount), and I'm not sure why.
2. Attempts to change the y-axis shows >5000 as blank.
3. The layout of the bars does not seem to match the lower 5000 of the target plot.

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=year, y=amount)) + stat_identity(geom = "bar", aes(fill=gender))
```

[image: Cropped, unsorted]

---

Update: 3

To a certain degree the desired results may be obtained by using the following code:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=year, y=amount, fill=gender, group = continent)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

However, the fact that you need to group on a second parameter to achieve this does not fit well with my target application. I'm looking for a completely unsorted plot where only the row numbers determines the stacking order.

[image: Grouped plot]

Comment: Link to blog by Christoph Herzog: [Link](https://theduke.at/blog/science/beginners-guide-to-creating-grouped-and-stacked-bar-charts-in-r-with-ggplot2/)

Comment: Your code is not reproducible for me. I get the scrambled results. Try restarting your R session and running just this code? (Edit: looking at the blog link, if you ran the second part of the code to make the ordered table then went back to the first part you should still get the ordered table because your data has been unscrambled)

Comment: @Bishops_Guest I've run the code on two different computers with clean RStudio sessions. However, I still see the unscrambled results. Could it be the version of ggplot? I'm really at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to update 3 of the Q, the OP is *looking for a completely unsorted plot where only the row numbers determines the stacking order*.

I believe this can be achieved with

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=year, y=amount, fill=gender, group=row.names(d))) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

The OP already had used `continent` as `group` aesthetic in his update 3. Here, the row number or row id as returned by `row.names(d)` is used to group the data.

`geom_col()` is a shortcut to `geom_bar(stat="identity")` introduced with `ggplot2` version 2.2.0.

Note that the results may differ as the OP has omitted `set.seed()` to *reproducibly* create sample data.

Comment: Did my post answer your question? If so, please, accept it by clicking on the green check mark in order to indicate other users that this question has been answerered. Please consider also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.